# Accessing nested arrays in PHP without many loops

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following:

```
$dropdown = array (
    "unitofmeasure" => array (
        "m"     => "meters",
        "ft"    => "feet"
    ),
    "facing_direction" => array (
        "0"     => array ("West","North-West","North","North-East","East","South-East"),
        "1"     => array("South","South-West")
    )
    .... 
)
```

Assume there are *n* number of sub arrays, not just the two shown above.

Iteration solution:

```
foreach($dropdown as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $k => $v) { 
        foreach($v as $id => $value) {
           //manipulate values here
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

> **is there not a more elegant solution available in PHP?** 
>   for example something like `foreach($dropdown->children()->children() ...)`

<sub>I know there are a few semi-similar questions on SO but they're slightly different and the answers are mediocre.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I personally tend to use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with a closure(if you're using PHP above 5.3).

You can, obviously, also use recursion if you like getting your hands dirty.

I suppose an example is in order:

```
$array = [ 0 => [0 => [ 0 => 1 ...]]];

$manipulated_array = [];

array_walk_recursive($array, function($value) use (&$manipulated_array)
{
  // do whatever you wish here
});
```

Comment: [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) would also be an option.

Comment: Good call, forgot about that one. Another option would be [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) - which has a silly name.

Answer (score 1):

foreach() just expects an array, so if you only need to iterate ONE of those deeply nested arrays, then you can quite easily have

```
foreach($arr['level1']['level2'][...]['levelGazillion'] as ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use recursion in these situations:

```
function modify_array(&$arr)
{
    if (is_array(arr)) {
        foreach($arr as &$val) {
            modify_array($val);
        }
    } else {
        modify_value($arr);
    }
}
```

where `modify_value(&$val)` is whatever you want to do to each non-array child at any arbitrary depth